# Creation of Microsoft Azure Web App with sql server failed

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I've been attempting to create a new MVC web application in visual studio and have it hosted in Microsoft Azure. If I choose to have a database server it fails with the following error.

> Creating Microsoft Azure Web App
>   Creation of Microsoft Azure Web App failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If I don't select the option to have a database the web site is created in my azure account.

Can anyone tell me what this error is suppose to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest SDK version. There was a bug in 2.5.1 that is fixed in 2.6. Also make sure you're creating the database in the same resource group as the web app.